# Why does the compiler shift left by 0?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++

After I wrote this simple program, when I went to the disassembly mode in Visual Studio I noticed something strange: the compiler added an instruction to shift left by 0 bits.

Why does it do that?

This is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    if (argc != 3)
        return 0;

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0) {
        printf("test");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the assembly code:

```
...
        return 0;
00131C94  xor         eax,eax  
00131C96  jmp         main+57h (0131CC7h)  

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0) {
00131C98  push        offset string "-r" (0138B30h)  
00131C9D  mov         eax,4  
00131CA2  shl         eax,0  <------------------------- HERE
00131CA5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [argv]  
00131CA8  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+eax]  
00131CAB  push        edx  
00131CAC  call        _strcmp (01313D9h)  
00131CB1  add         esp,8  
00131CB4  test        eax,eax  
00131CB6  jne         main+55h (0131CC5h)  
        printf("test");
00131CB8  push        offset string "test" (0138BD0h)  
00131CBD  call        _printf (01313E8h)  
00131CC2  add         esp,4  
...
```

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations?

Comment: It seems to only add the shift for x86, not x64. Also seems to disappear for Release build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that this is used in the evaluation of `argv[1]`.

In general, `argv[N]` needs to be translated by the compiler to `*((char**) ((char*) argv + N * sizeof *argv))`: each pointer is `sizeof *argv` bytes after the next. When `N` is not known at compile-time, the multiplication needs to be there, and `shl` is the normal way of doing this.<sup>*</sup>

Since `N` is known at compile-time, but you've not enabled optimisations, I would have guessed this would compile to

```
00131C9D  mov         eax,1
00131CA2  shl         eax,2
```

Apparently Visual Studio is able to simplify this to what you're seeing even when optimisations are disabled, but without optimisations, it still isn't able to get rid of the `shl` entirely.

<sub><sup>*</sup> In this specific case, `shl` wouldn't be needed even if `N` is not known at compile-time: `[ecx+eax*4]` can be accessed with a single instruction. That would be another optimisation that would normally be performed.</sub>

Comment: I suppose MSVC performs strength reductions in the frontend, which makes sense as it is based on pcc (which IIRC also does this).